# List Converts to Blank Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My list `xfrs`, returns a blank DF when I convert it....does anyone see any issues with the code?

I'm able to append and print the list fine, but when I append, the DF `transfers` is blank.

```
url2 = 'https://247sports.com/Season/2020-Football/TransferPortalPositionRanking/'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}



response = requests.get(url2, headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
xfrs = []
schools = []
for li in soup.findAll('li', attrs={'class':'transfer-player'}):
    xfrs.append(li.find('a').contents)
    schools.append(li.find('li', attrs={'class':'destination'}))


transfers = pd.DataFrame(xfrs, columns=['Players'])
print(transfers)
```

Comment: try  `print(li.find('a').contents)` before appending it to **xfrs** to check if it has any content

Comment: `.contents` returns a list of Beautiful Soup objects. You probably want `.string`.

Comment: @FerasAlfrih it does have contents

Comment: @barmar when i do that, it returns 'none' for each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, `.contents` returns a list of BeautifulSoup objects, so you need to use for example `.text` to get the name. Also take care of your selection it should be more specific.

Storing the scraped data in a dataframe try to collect it as list of dicts:

```
data.append({
        'Player':li.h3.text,
        'Destination':destination['alt'] if (destination:=li.select_one('img[class="logo"]')) else None
    })
```

#### Example

```
import requests,json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url2 = 'https://247sports.com/Season/2020-Football/TransferPortalPositionRanking/'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url2, headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
data = []
for li in soup.find_all('li', attrs={'class':'transfer-player'}):
    data.append({
        'Player':li.h3.text,
        'Destination':destination['alt'] if (destination:=li.select_one('img[class="logo"]')) else None
    })



pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Output

| Player | Destination |
| --- | --- |
| JT Daniels | Georgia |
| KJ Costello | Mississippi State |
| Jamie Newman | Georgia |
| ... | ... |

Comment: thank you very much. this is exactly what i needed as it only includes the text of the link as well.